# Why is Pycharm Community Edition Saying 'Unresolved Reference'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, editor, pycharm

Why is Pycharm Community Edition Saying 'Unresolved Reference myfolder'? My Python code runs without errors.

```
from myfolder.client import Client
```

Comment: Some times it helps if you add an empty `__init__.py` file in the folder myfolder or if the myfolder is your root folder mark it as [Source Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it happens sometimes. If it really annoys you go to `File`, then `Invalidate caches/restart`.

Comment: No. It's just confused.